# Autoscrolling to textBox's last row line in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, autoscroll

I'm using the multi-line textbox(txtMsgBox) with vertical scrolling. I'm using this textbox like Message Log for my tool but there's problem it doesn't auto-scroll it to the last row with below code. Am I missing something?

```
Public Shared Sub WriteConsoleMsg(ByVal ConsoleMsgType As String, ByVal ConsoleMsg As String)
    Main.txtMsgBox.AppendText(ConsoleMsgType & vbTab & ConsoleMsg & vbCrLf)
    Main.txtMsgBox.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't actually reproduce this problem. Simply calling `AppendText()` causes the TextBox to scroll to the end. Even `ScrollToCaret()` is redundant in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't miss anything - somehow it does not work with the `TextBox` (WinForms!) control. If it's not a problem change the `TextBox` control to a `RichTextBox` control. Then your method will work as expected.

TextBox does not work for me either:

[image]

RichTextBox works like a charm:

[image]

Another option would be to manipulate the scrollbar of the textbox, but IMO this makes the solution unnecessary complicated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what VS version and FW version was this tested on? In VS 2017 and Fw 4.7.1, both controls behave the same.